# Real time data update

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, parse-platform, real-time

My app uses google map to show user's location in real time. Therefore I would like it to be updated with every data change on my Parse server.

I've looked all over the net and as I see it I have 3 options:

1. using syncAdapter - the problem is that everywhere it is written that it does not meant for real time data transfer (I don't really understand why), on other hand it must be more efficient than updating every 5 sec.
2. using asyncTask - the problem is that it probably consumes a lot of battery and data usage to run it every 5 sec.
3. using service - same problem as asyncTask.

As i'm very confused, please help me understand what is the appropriate way to implement my real time map.
Thank's all

Comment: If you care about Battery then why __Google__ developed __Google Play Services__?? best option is Services running in background

Comment: i'm using GCM for my applications. when server have data updated then server send broadcast. the client receive broadcast then run the update

Comment: @MD I didn't understand your sentence. As I understand it, by using service I would have to make a request every few seconds to make it look like real time. Doesn't it consume a lot of battery??

Comment: @evyamiz It's consume lots of battery but we have no way. As __Google__ do the same. If they doesn't care about Battery then why should you?

Comment: @MD Thanks for your answer. Fair enough, I didn't look at it that way.. Though I was sure there is more elegant way to do it

Answer (score 0):

The best way i know is to use LocationListener to update the location only if it has been changed. You can use the onLocationChanged() method to update the location.

```
public class LocationHelper {
    private  LocationManager locationManager;
    private  Location currentLocation;

    public LocationHelper(Context context) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        currentLocation = location;
    }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            setLocation(location);//Only update location if it has changed.
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
}
```

If the location hasn't been changed, you can just remember the last known location.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but your answer refer to the way I can show myself continuously, but I meant to ask what is the appropriate way to show all other users continuously..